# RESTKit: Duplicate Objects in relationship after POST

Tags: core-data, ios7, restkit-0.20

Below is my setup:

```
- (RKManagedObjectStore *)setupCoreDataWithRESTKit
{
    NSError * error;
    NSURL * modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"App" ofType:@"momd"]];
    NSManagedObjectModel * managedObjectModel = [[[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL] mutableCopy];
    self.managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];

    [self.managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];

    NSArray * searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString * documentPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSPersistentStore * persistentStore = [self.managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/App%@.sqlite", documentPath, [TBSPersistence username]] fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil withConfiguration:nil options:[self optionsForSqliteStore] error:&error];
    NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store with error: %@", error);

    NSLog(@"Path: %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/App%@.sqlite", documentPath, [TBSPersistence username]]);

    if(!persistentStore){
        NSLog(@"Failed to add persistent store: %@", error);
    }

    [self.managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

    return self.managedObjectStore;
}
```

POST Invite -- Invite has a to-many relationship with Activity::

```
-(void)sendInvite:(NSInteger)methodType
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.objectManager = [self getObjectManager];
    self.objectManager.managedObjectStore = appDelegate.managedObjectStore;

    RKEntityMapping *invitationMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:kInvite
                                                             inManagedObjectStore:self.objectManager.managedObjectStore];



    RKEntityMapping *activityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:kActivity
                                                           inManagedObjectStore:self.objectManager.managedObjectStore];


    Invite *invitation;


            invitationMapping = [RESTMappingProvider invitionPostMapping:invitationMapping];
            invitationMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"inviteId"];

            activityMapping =  [RESTMappingProvider activityPostMapping:activityMapping];
           activityMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"activityId"];

            [invitationMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:kActivitiesRelationship
                                                                                              toKeyPath:kActivitiesRelationship
                                                                                            withMapping:activityMapping]];
            invitation = [self setupInviteProperties:STPOST];
            [self setupDescriptors:invitationMapping andKeyPath:kKeyPath descriptorClass:0];

            [self.objectManager.HTTPClient  registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];

            [self.objectManager postObject:invitation path:kKeyPath parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
            } 
            failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            }];

        }

     }
```

Descriptor:

```
-(void)setupDescriptors:(RKEntityMapping *)invitationMapping andKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath descriptorClass:(BOOL)isTemplate
{

RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:[invitationMapping inverseMapping] objectClass:[Invite class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodAny];

NSIndexSet *statusCodeSet = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful);

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:invitationMapping
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                   pathPattern:keyPath
                                                                                       keyPath:nil
                                                                                   statusCodes:statusCodeSet];

self.objectManager.requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
[self.objectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
[self.objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
```

}

I `POST` just fine.  When I get a `Response`, I get the assigned ID's, for the created objects in the database, back from the server.

`POSTING:`  `@"inviteId" : @"0"    @"activityId" : @"0"`

In response, I get everything back as POSTED, however, the server issues Real IDs.

`RESPONSE:`  `@"inviteId" : @"123456"    @"activityId" : @"234567"`

Problem:

`invite` Object gets updated with the assigned ID auto-magically; however, the activity objects become duplicates in CoreData (.sqlite) with one of the duplicate will have `@"0"` as the `activityID`, while its duplicate will have the assigned Id `@"234567"`

Later when I `GET, only the assigned Id object (`@"234567"`) get updated.  Objects with`@"0"` Id's are never touched and remain in Core Data.

Question:  How can I avoid the duplicate record and why is this not happening to the `invite` Object

*** UPDATE ***

Returned JSON:

```
{
    "inviteId": 226,
    "meetingType": 2,
    "activities": [{
        "locationAddress": "4th Floor",
        "startTime": "2014-05-07T01:15:23Z",
        "activityId": 263,
        "latitude": "0",
        "longitude": "0",
        "meetupId": 226,
        "locationName": "West Conference Room",
        "oldId": -7360
    }, {
        "locationAddress": "123 Main St. ",
        "startTime": "2014-05-06T20:15:45Z",
        "activityId": 264,
        "latitude": "0",
        "longitude": "0",
        "meetupId": 226,
        "locationName": "Starwood Building",
        "oldId": -9325
    }],
    "comment": "Comments",
    "status": 0,
    "senderId": "Userid",
    "startDate": "2014-05-07T13:15:00Z"
}
```

`activities` is the name of the relationship between `Invite` & `Activity` entities

Comment: Is the JSON returned an array when it doesn't work? Show the JSON and a trace log.

Comment: Yes...Invite is a dictionary, and "activities" is an array with "Activity" objects.  I updated the question with the returned JSON.  Thank you!

Comment: So, you are posting one invitation with nested activities, and getting all of those objects back with identifiers (and only the invitation gets updated, not the activities) - correct?

Comment: Yes.  activities objects are not updated, instead created as duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected (if perhaps not ideal) outcome - RestKit is only able to map the response onto the sent object (not its relationships).

A good option could be to use fetch request blocks to find and purge the orphan activity objects at a later date (it wouldn't run after the POST, so you would need to manually find and delete if you needed the dead objects removed immediately).

Comment: Thanks. When should it run?  Inside the success block?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to fetch all the items with @"0" ID's assigned and delete them in the success block of the POST?

Comment: Yes, that is the manual option. Not a lot more code than the fetch alone. Just remember you need to explicitly save afterwards. Technically you could delete them immediately after you make the request is sent but the success block is an easy trigger...

Comment: last question:  I'm using self.object manager. I know with RKManagedObjectRequestOperation I can do operation.savesToPersistentStore = NO).  I'm hoping I can do the same with ObjectManager and once I delete the @"0" id from the context, I can save it to the localStore?

Comment: I don't think you can do that (though I haven't tried / checked). It runs on a background thread so would be hard to achieve (safely / correctly).