# RestKit POSTed managed object becomes duplicate when response is enveloped in an array

Tags: ios, json, core-data, restkit

When I POST a Core Data managed object using RestKit, RestKit doesn't update the existing object but creates a new object instead.

The returned JSON always contains the newly created object, but wraps it into a plural keyed array. I found that if I change this to just the one object, the updating works as expected. However, I would like to keep the array in the response so that all responses are consistently in the plural form.

Is there any way I can make RestKit update the record, even when returned from the server wrapped in an array?

**Possible solution: `identificationAttribute`?**

On my entities I have an `identificationAttribute` called `remoteID`. This is the primary unique key of the record. This will be 0 before the POST, because the object is not yet on the server. I thought that by adding a second identificationAttribute called `insertionID`, setting that before the POST, and then returning it in the response, would allow RK to find the existing entity in the local store. Alas, it didn't work.

What did work however, was setting the `remoteID` before the POST, to the next auto increment value on the server! What could explain that it works with `remoteID`, but not with a second `insertionID`?

**Example request**

```
{
    "user": {
        "email": "example@example.com"
    }
}
```

**Response**

```
{
    "users": [{
        "email": "example@example.com"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to keep the array in the response so that all responses are consistently in the plural form.

You shouldn't, because this is an individual request and response, not a composite.

Your idea about `identificationAttribute` is correct, but doesn't apply when the response is an array. The array is the trigger (or one of the possible triggers) to abandon the match with the source object and create new objects. Changing this would be hard.

Without knowing more about your real situation, 2 alternatives:

1. Change the JSON
2. POST a dictionary instead of the real object and then you won't have a duplicate

---

When you use multiple identification attributes, all must match for the destination object to be found.

Take care - don't create multiple mappings for the same entity with different identification attributes or you will most likely be debugging the lookup cache for a long time trying to work out what's happening...

If the identity matches before the request is made then the array isn't an issue. To explain the above in more detail:

When you POST an object, RestKit expects to get that object back. So, if you POST one object and get an array back it doesn't know what to do, because it can't map an array into an object. So, it tries to lookup based on the identification attribute (if they exist). If the POSTed object didn't have an id and the returned object does then it will never match. If you set it before POSTing then it will match.

Comment: It could ditch the array, but then I will need to create extra response descriptors. And what if I want to post multiple objects? Surely I need an array response then. I find it very strange that RK doesn't use the identification attribute to fetch the existing entities from the Core Data store when the response is an array. Would it change if I also posted an array? I had that first, but it didn't work either.

Comment: I don't recall if posting an array checks against an array response contents. If you posted multiple objects I'd usually expect to receive a list of status / id responses back rather than full objects necessarily. Remember that RestKit is trying to cater for the 'norms' and that you can find things it doesn't do. You could fork it and suggest changes (on github).

Comment: Hi Wain, I've added some new information to my question regarding the `identificationAttribute`. Could you maybe shed some light on that unexpected behavior?

Comment: Ah, so an extra attribute isn't going to work because _all_ attributes must match. Thanks!

Comment: Oh boy, I've got a feeling there's a lot of trouble ahead... After fixing this issue even more issues popped up with RK not mapping onto the existing CoreData entities. I've got three levels of relationship nesting, where I want to only POST the first two levels. Result: RestKit successfully maps onto the first entity, the second level entities are duplicated, and the third level entities are orphaned as is. Is there any way I could get this to work with RK, or is this just not the way to go?

Comment: FIY: I've created an issue for this on Github: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/1970

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23485863/restkit-duplicate-objects-in-relationship-after-post

Comment: You're definitely walking the boundary. You will likely be better served by not trying to use the automatic POST mapping back to the source object or changing the JSON to separate the data differently.

Comment: Yeah I got that feeling as well. Hopefully the idea I proposed on GitHub can be worked in. In any case, thanks for your input so far. You truly are the RestKit god around here, haha.